# MetadataExtractor not extract data from video file

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, metadata, metadata-extractor

I am using `MetadataExtractor` library for extract data from image. it works fine.

please see myy below code.

```
  IEnumerable<MetadataExtractor.Directory> directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(file)
```

but it's not working with video (.mp4) file.

```
MetadataExtractor.Formats.QuickTime.QuickTimeMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
```

Actually i want to extract GPS data from image and video. it's work with images but not work or not properly extracted the data from video files.

Please see sample extraction data of video.

[image]

In the image you can see the Matrix data. I think actually it's a list data.

but it's retrived like a string data. is there any idea.

Any advice much appreaciated.